# How to copy files whose name contains number from 20 to 32

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, command

I want to copy files from the copyDest to pastDest that contain number from 20 to 32. What am I dong wrong?

```
cp -r ~/copyDest/*2[0-9]|3[0-2]* ~/pasteDest
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`|` is the pipeline operator.

```
cp -r ~/copyDest/*2[0-9]|3[0-2]* ~/pasteDest
```

is the `cp` command piped to the command whose name is the first file expanded from the `3[0-2]*` glob. For `|` to be a glob alternation operator, it has be within `(...)` in `zsh` (but `zsh` has a dedicated operator for number range matching) and `@(...)` in `ksh` (or `bash` with `extglob` on).

So, with `zsh`:

```
cp -r ~/copyDest/(*[^0-9]|)<20-32>(|[^0-9]*) ~/pasteDest
```

Without the `(*[^0-9]|)`, it would also match on foo120

With `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` (or use `shopt -s extglob` within `bash`) or `zsh -o kshglob` (`set -o kshglob` within `zsh`), the equivalent (except for the order in which the files are copied) would look like:

```
(
  LC_ALL=C
  cp -r ~/copyDest/?(*[^0-9])*(0)@(2[0-9]|3[0-2])?([^0-9]*) ~/pasteDest
)
```

With ksh or bash, on most systems and most locales other than C, `[0-9]` matches a lot more characters than 0123456789, hence the `LC_ALL=C` (which also affects the glob expansion sorting order). If your file names contain only ASCII characters, you may omit it, as I don't think any locale on any sane system would have ASCII characters other than 0123456789 matched by `[0-9]`. Other alternative is to replace `[0-9]` with `[0123456789]`.

Also note that except in `zsh -o kshglob`, if the pattern doesn't match any file, `cp` will be called with a literal `.../?(*[^0-9])*(0)@(2[0-9]|3[0-2])?([^0-9]*)` argument (a valid though unlikely file name) which if it exists would then be copied (or `cp` would return an error otherwise). In `bash`, you can use the `failglob` option to get a behaviour closer to `zsh`'s saner one (of cancelling the command if the pattern doesn't match).

Above we take special care of copying files named `foo20.txt`, `foo00020.txt`, but not `foo120.txt` or `foo200.txt` (even though their name contains 20). It  still copies `foo32.12.txt` or `foo-1E-20.txt` or `foo0x20.txt` files.

If you still want to copy `foo120` or `foo200` files, then it becomes much simpler:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  cp -r ~/copyDest/*<20-32>* ~/pasteDest
  ```
- `bash -O extglob` and co:

  ```
  cp -r ~/copyDest/*@(2[0123456789]|3[012])* ~/pasteDest
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You failed to read the manual on shell pattern matching and assumed that it is the same as what is commonly called "regular expressions". Just the fact that the `*` operator, that you use in your example, has a different meaning should be a hint that they are not the same.

With bash (and some other shells) you can use the `{,}` operator for the desired effect:

```
cp -r ~/copyDest/*{2[0-9],3[0-2]}* ~/pasteDest
```

But beware there are differences. This is the same as writing

```
cp -r ~/copyDest/*2[0-9]* ~/copyDest/*3[0-2]* ~/pasteDest
```

That means if either of the patterns doesn't match any file, it will be passed as an argument to `cp`, and `cp` will complain that the file doesn't exist. You can set the `nullglob` shell option to avoid that.

Comment: Note that it would copy a `foo200.txt` or `foo120.txt` file as well.

Comment: There's no need to be condescending... at first sight they look similar. The rest of the answer is useful though, thanks.

Comment: The OP's attempt, if it worked, would also match ```foo200.txt``` or ```foo120.txt``` so presumably those matches are prohibited by the larger unstated context of OP's situation; perhaps the log files are only numbered from 1 - 64.

Comment: I mean, absent some sort of additional constraints to the contrary, `foo200.txt` _does_ contain the number "20" in its filename.

Answer (score 6):

`bash` approach.  As a bonus it prints the numbers for which a matching file was not fou nd.

```
[steve@instance-2 ~]$ find copyDest pasteDest
copyDest
copyDest/file15
copyDest/file20
copyDest/file25
copyDest/file32
copyDest/file33
pasteDest
[steve@instance-2 ~]$ cp -pr ~/copyDest/*{20..32}* pasteDest
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*21*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*22*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*23*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*24*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*26*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*27*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*28*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*29*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*30*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/steve/copyDest/*31*’: No such file or directory
[steve@instance-2 ~]$ find copyDest pasteDest
copyDest
copyDest/file15
copyDest/file20
copyDest/file25
copyDest/file32
copyDest/file33
pasteDest
pasteDest/file20
pasteDest/file25
pasteDest/file32
[steve@instance-2 ~]$
```

Comment: Note that it would copy a `foo200.txt` or `foo120.txt` file as well.

Comment: This approach (or zsh's `<20-32>`) is cleanest as it doesn't require the human to reverse engineer a pattern from a numeric sequence.

Answer (score 5):

When I need to deal with numbered files, I tend to use a for loop and `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 20 32); do cp -r ~/copyDest/*${i}* ~/pasteDest; done
```

Comment: Also the `-w` switch is useful if the numbers need to be padded with zeros: `seq -w 0 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Yoe need to do pattern matching, NOT regex matching. Look into your shell's man page. Try something like

```
ls  *2[0-9]* *3[0-2]*
```

i.e. implement the alternation by supplying two patterns.

Comment: Note that it would copy a `foo200.txt` or `foo120.txt` file as well.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: which is what the OP requested: "contain number from 20 to 32". 120 does contain such. But, I see your point.

Comment: Yes, it was a _note_, not an objection. Something the OP possibly hadn't considered.